# AVFoundation AVPlayer seekToTime completionHandler syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, avfoundation

Probably a simple question for iOS5
They have changed the seekToTime method of AVFoundation to look like this:

```
[avPlayer seekToTime:startTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished)completionHandler];
```

The constants kCMTimeZero and startTime are our own variables of type CMTime.  Fine.

But I have NEVER seen the ^(BOOL finished) before, and don't really know what to give it.  There are no examples that I can see online (or in the apple doc).
I'm assuming that I need to give it a selector that will be called when the seekToTime is complete, but can't figure out the right syntax.  Can anybody give me the correct useage of this method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It expects a regular objective-c block that accepts a `BOOL` parameter that indicates "whether the seek operation completed" (quoted from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime%3atoleranceBefore%3atoleranceAfter%3acompletionHandler%3a)).

```
[avPlayer seekToTime:time1 
    toleranceBefore:time2 
    toleranceAfter:time3 
    completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished)
            /* do stuff */
        else
            /* do other stuff */
    }];
```